# php exec() : ant wont run nor output

Tags: php, ant

I've been trying to run an Ant script from PHP with the "system" and then the "exec" function.

My ant script works, I can call it from the command line, its all fine. But when it comes to call it from php, it doesn't work and I can't achieve to get the output for debugging.

Here's my call :

```
exec("ant -buildfile ".$scriptname." -DInputPath=\"../uploads/".$file."\" -DOutputDir=\"./output/".$newfile."\" convert" , $output,$return_value);
```

Knowing that :

```
file_exists($scriptname); //returns true,
$output; //is empty
$return_value; //is set to 1.
```

The ant script I use for testing just have a copy task like this (in a target named "convert") :

```
copy file="${InputPath}" tofile="${OutputDir}"
```

Regards,
Brice.

Comment: probably your PHP process does not have enough permissions to create a new ant process. So i'd check the permissions and add the the ant/php in the same group.

Comment: try to give full path of ant command.